# android problems with pinch to zoom libraries PhotoView and TouchImageView on portrait images

Tags: android, pinchzoom, portrait

I want to display images and allow pinch to zoom.  My app is a blank activity with a linear layout with ImageView on top and under it a horizontal linear layout with some buttons.
I have tried both 
[PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) and [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView)
They both have similar problems:

1. the toolbar menu on right doesn't respond to touch (in 4.4.4 and 4.4.2).
   It seems to respond in 5.0.2.
2. photos taken in portrait mode do not display or zoom properly: they only use a portion of the ImageView.

I have looked at the code from TouchImageView and think I can see the answer to problem 2:  The routines get the width and height from code like :

```
float w = getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
```

To properly display a portrait mode photo in my app I need to do this

```
imageRotation = getOrientation(photoFilePath);
imgView.setRotation(imageRotation);
```

This rotates the photo for display, but the intrinsicWidth and intrinsicHeight do not change.  So the zooming software has the wrong dimensions.  Strange that this has not been caught before.  (Maybe it is my mistake.)
If I am right then I need to change the code so that the imgView.ROTATION property is tested.

Edit: I can detect rotation and then switch height and width in portrait mode images.  This helps a little, but is not enough.  There is still unused blank space in the imageview.  More work would be needed and this is beyond my skills.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am using https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view. Give it a try! It's awesome, the only downside is that you'll need to implement the things like hide Toolbar on touch yourself, but that's not very difficult.

Comment: Hi.  I read an image from file, get the bitmap, then modify the bitmap and display that.  Can I use this library to display the bitmap?

Comment: Yes you can, but there is a thing that I am walking into right now as well with bitmaps: the zooming and dragging of the image is significantly slower when using a bitmap that is in memory. I suggest you to save the edited image first and then display it with this library.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure this out.  My problem was how I rotated the portrait images to get them into the correct orientation on the screen.  I used

```
        imgView.setRotation((float)imageRotation);
```

That caused the problem!
Doing it this way (i.e. not using the imageView functionality)

```
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(imageRotation);
    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp , 0, 0, bmp .getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

worked.